# SQL select returns extra result

Tags: sql, sqlbase, centura

Guess there are similar questions and the answere might is easy but I cant help my self and thats why I ask you guys.

I have some Data in a DB (Centura/Gupta SQLBase 7) 
***no Left/Right Join possible - obviously not implemented in sqlbase sql***

Here is my select

```
SELECT 
    I.IARTNR, 
    L.ARTNAME 
FROM 
    INVENTUR I,
    LAGER L 
WHERE 
    L.ARTSTR = I.IARTNR 
AND
    I.AB = '2015-81';
```

returns 20 rows, not 18 as expacted.

`INVENTUR` rows with `AB` set to `2015-81` are 18 and in `LAGER` there are `<3000` rows. What I'm trying to do is select all articles von `INVENTUR` and add the article name thats written in `LAGER`.

Whats wrong with my select ? Running this "mysterious" since 3 days.

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT in SELECT statement?

Comment: using distinct will propably cause problems when there are duplicated entrys. of course its and and should be possible to add duplicates like artnr 1234 amount 1 artnr 1234 amount 1 (what should return artnr 1234 total amount is 2) btw with distinct it returns only 14 rows because some artcle have the same name but different artno.

Comment: Must you use that weird DB that does not have joins?

Comment: sadly yes :( there are some customers (about 200) of my company and they use sell software based on this DB....

Comment: Have you tried using sub queries instead

Comment: after almost 3 days I found out that lager has 3 articles that 100% duplicate. duplicates in iventur is no problem but in lager it is. so cleaned up the 3 articles and that solved the result. thx for alle hints and helps!

Comment: Thanks for the update Mr Dwza.                                                              Mr Basco FYI: SQLBase supports the following types of joins: • Equijoins • Outer joins • Self joins • Non-equijoins Heres a link to SQLBase online Help - support.guptatechnologies.com/supportwiki/index.php/ …

Answer (score 1):

ANSI join syntax for Outer / Inner joins was added in v8.5 onwards ( now upto v12.1 ). 
Before v8.5 , you can use the native Gupta Outer / Inner join syntax e.g.

```
SELECT t1.col1,t2.col1,t1.col2,t2.col2
FROM t1,t2
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1(+)
AND   t1.col2 = t2.col2(+)
```

The next example lists customer names and their order numbers,including customers who have made no orders:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTNO,NAME
FROM CUSTOMER,ORDERS
WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTNO = ORDERS.CUSTNO(*)
```

The same query using ANSI syntax in SQLBase v8.5 onmwards is:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTNO,NAME 
FROM CUSTOMER LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMER.CUSTNO = ORDERS.CUSTNO
```

Comment: As you can See in my sample, I use this way of select allready. The db is a 7.0.5 when I remember right. But thx for these informations.

Comment: But why did you answered my question 2 times? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit joins.

```
SELECT I.IARTNR, L.ARTNAME 
FROM INVENTUR I
INNER JOIN LAGER L ON I.IARTNR = L.ARTSTR
WHERE I.AB = '2015-81';
```

And if needs be `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.IARTNR, L.ARTNAME 
FROM INVENTUR I
INNER JOIN LAGER L ON I.IARTNR = L.ARTSTR
WHERE I.AB = '2015-81';
```

Comment: as i sayed... i cant use join..obviously this command isnt implemented in that sql.

Comment: For the record, SQLBase DOES fully support explicit ANSI joins as stated by Matt and earlier.   Just include ANSIJoinSyntax=1 in the [dbntsrv] of sql.ini

Answer (score 0):

Of course SQLBase has inner / outer joins ! 
Either Native syntax ( using (+) ) or ANSI .
Here's the syntax:

NATIVE: 
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 (+) AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 (+);

ANSI:
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2
FROM t2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN t1
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 ;

p.s. SQLBase is no 'weird' database . v12 recently released will outstrip SQLServer every time in terms of performance , footprint and overall cost of ownership. Please be more aware of your facts before broadcasting nonsense.

Comment: Mr Dwza :   If you cant use inner/outer joins in SQLBase - your doing it wrong .  SQLBase supports all the following in either Native or ANSI formats : SQLBase supports the following types of joins:
• Equijoins
• Outer joins
• Self joins
• Non-equijoins   Heres a link to SQLBase online Help - which you obviously could make use of . http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportwiki/index.php/SQLBase_12_Documentation

Comment: First of all, thanks for this informations. Even if your answere was kind of "flaming". As you can see I sayed **obviously** didnt say thats is NOT implemented. I also never sayed its a 'weird' database!!! Its fine that SB12 was released and thats it is fast... This fact doesnt matters to my point of problem. We use version 7 and yes, i'm sure that v12 has good improvements!... Anyway... i tried your given syntax and it still drops syntax error. Btw. the issue was caused by failed data in db.